# How to determine the signature of a Hermitian form

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, quadratic-forms

When tasked to find the rank/signature of say $16xy-z^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$, I proceed by writing it in the form $(2x+2y)^2-(2x-2y)^2-z^2$, and concluding that the rank is $3$, say.

For Hermitian forms, does this equivalent procedure involve using modulus brackets, or standard square brackets? I.e. if I can write a Hermitian form as $\psi(x, x) = a|A(x)|^2+b|B(x)|^2+c|C(x)|^2$ (where $a, b, c$ are all $+1$ or $-1$), can I conclude that the rank is $3$? As an example, consider [Finding the rank and signature of a hermitian form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614252/finding-the-rank-and-signature-of-a-hermitian-form)

Comment: It depends on whether your $A$, $B$, $C$ define a rank $3$ matrix. In your quadratic form example, the point is that $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ has rank $3$.

Comment: @CaptainLama So why does modulus work in the Hermitian example??